# prefix and middleware not working for some reason. for some routes

Tags: php, laravel

so im trying to put my localization as prefix on my website domain so i made a middleware the puts the localization lang on the url ever time you try to open a page heres my middleware

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->method() === 'GET') {
        $segment = $request->segment(1);


        if (!in_array($segment, config('app.locales'))) {
            $segments = $request->segments();
            $fallback = session('locale') ?: config('app.fallback_locale');
            $segments = array_prepend($segments, $fallback);

            return redirect()->to(implode('/', $segments));
        }

        session(['locale' => $segment]);
        app()->setLocale($segment);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

and i added the middleware to the routemiddleware

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'Locate' =>  \App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class,
];
```

and i did put a prefix and middleware to all my routes like this

```
Route::prefix('{lang?}')->middleware('Locate')->group(function() {

Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');


Route::get('/admin/login', function () {
    return view('admin.auth.login');
})->name('AdminLogin');


Route::get('/contact-us', 'ContactUsController@Contactus')->name('ContactUs');
Route::post('/contact-us', 'ContactUsController@PostContactus')->name('PostContactUs');




Route::prefix('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', function () {
        return view('auth.login');
    })->name('Login');

    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@Login')->name('userslogin');

});



Route::prefix('search')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/categories', 'search\SearchController@Categories')->name('Categories');
    Route::get('/filter/{categoryseo}', 'search\SearchController@filter')->name('InstructorsSearch');
    //sending categoryseo to the filter page so i can put it in hidden input in the filter page and use it to get the list

    Route::get('/list', 'search\SearchController@InstructorList')->name('InstructorsSearchList');
    Route::get('/profile/{userid?}', 'search\SearchController@instructorprofile')->name('InstructorProfile');
});

});
```

for some reason pages like /home gets the to the middleware and change as i wanted like this /en/home , as for other like search/categories it wont even notice my middleware but i tried to remove the prefix of the localization and just put my middleware it worked and it notice my middleware. using laravel 5.5

Comment: Is the middleware working on `/auth/...` (like `/en/auth/login`) routes ? What routes, do you have while calling `php artisan route:list' ?

Comment: yeah they do work

Comment: What about my second question? Are you sure, that you are not overriding `/search/...` routes definitions anywhere else ?

Comment: im 100% sure...

Comment: and your routes?

Comment: php artisan route:list doesn't even work in this project

Comment: Then you have the hint right now... It needs to produce result, without any errors, for route declarations to properly work. What error do you get?

Comment: Undefined offset: 2

Comment: you need to give more detailed answers (full error description, with exact line and script causing problem). Without that, it is impossible to help...